# Browserstack multiple automate test running

Tags: behat, mink, browserstack

We use the Behat - Mink for the local test, but now we should integrate the BrowserStack with parallel running. I was able to set up the single running, what is very nice, but I can not figure out how could I set up the multiple capabilities or environment? Thank you for the help.

This is my behat.yml now

```
legacy_browserstack:
autoload:
    '': '%paths.base%/root/tests/behat/bootstrap'
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url:  'https://master.staging2.dealtrak123.co.uk/'
        sessions:
            edge:
                browser_stack:
                    username: "username"
                    access_key: "key"
                    capabilities: {"browser" : "Edge", "os": "Windows", "os_version": "10", "browserstack-debug": true}    
suites:
    default:
        paths: [ %paths.base%/root/tests/behat/features ]
        contexts:
            - Fsuk\Behat\Legacy\LegacyFeatureContext
```

Comment: From what I know, I dont think behat-mink supports maxInstances capability which means you will have to create a custom solution to run parallel tests

Comment: What you can do is split your tests into several suites and run each suite in a node, that’s what I did for scrutinizer

Comment: I know this is only Behat.. (and not Behat-Mink) but see if this helps:
https://www.browserstack.com/automate/behat#running-parallel-tests

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from the BrowserStack support and they said, the parallel test for the browserstack session is not available currently, they don't support it, but that is on the road map.